# CentOS 8: Clonezilla image fails to boot when applied

Tags: system-installation, disk-image, clonezilla

Imaging CentOS 8 with Clonezilla consistently fails to make an image I can successfully replay onto a different drive and boot from.

I downloaded the CentOS installation ISO and verified it with SHA256 before writing it to a LiveUSB with http://rufus.ie , and installed CentOS successfully. Next, I booted from a Clonezilla LiveUSB (Clonezilla-live-20191024-eoan0amd64.iso also verified) and imaged the four partitions, saved the image on another USB flash drive, then shut down and changed the internal drive so I could replay the image.

Partitions are:

> sda1   1 GB /boot/efi  FAT32 aka EFI Partition
>   sda2   1 GB /boot      ext4
>   sda3   4 GB swap
>   sda4 200 GB root       ext4

When I rebooted with Clonezilla and replayed the image just made, then shut down, remove Clonezilla, and boot from that new drive, CentOS fails.

I reviewed the eight relevant posts here at https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=CentOS+Clonezilla+-pxe+-VM+-LVM but none provided a useful answer. I'm using GPT instead of MBR.

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Imaging each partition on a drive with Clonezilla was the point of failure. Once I imaged the entire disk in one swell foop, then I could make an image which, when written to a new drive, was reliable.